Perpendiculars in 3 dimensions
I was looking for the proof for the distributive property of the dot-product with the definition that $\vec a \cdot \vec b = ab\cos\theta$ as I came across the second proof of this page: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dot_Product_Distributes_over_Addition
It directly deduces that $UA∥CB$ which is strange to me. How do you prove that $UA∥CB$?
I think that proving $CB$ is perpendicular to the first instance of $\vec w$ is easier and more reasonable. How can you prove that the line passing through the foots of the perpendiculars to 2 parallel lines from a point outside of their plane is perpendicular to these lines?

As an FYI: MSE is not a "do my (home)work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") are often in poor taste, downvoted, & closed; we expect users to actively put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is helpful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 can help find past questions.

@PrincessEev I edited my question. Is it better now?

Now you are asking about the justification of a specific step in an already-published proof on a well-known website. The question looks fine to me in this form.

I agree that it seems slightly easier to prove that $CB$ is perpendicular to the first instantiation of $\mathbf w$ than to prove that $UA \parallel CB$.
Once you have done that, from the fact that the points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $U$ all lie in the plane containing the two instantiations of $\mathbf w$ and the fact that $UA$ and $CB$ both are perpendicular to $AB$, it follows that $UA \parallel CB$.
The proof leaves some of the steps of the geometric construction to the reader. Having omitted the steps to show that $CB \perp \mathbf w$, it also omits the additional step to show from this that $UA \parallel CB$.

In my opinion, a slightly simpler and more obvious approach would be to construct two planes perpendicular to $\mathbf w$, one through the point $U$ and one through the point $V$ as shown in the figure.
The points $A$, $B$, and $C$ are then the remaining intersections of these two planes with the two instantiations of $\mathbf w$ shown in the figure.
Because these two planes are each perpendicular to $\mathbf w$, it follows that $UA$, $VB$, and $VC$ are each perpendicular to each instantiation of $\mathbf w$ that they intersect. This establishes all three of the perpendicular relationships marked in the figure.
Because the two planes are perpendicular to the same vector, they are parallel.
Because the planes are parallel, their intersections with a third plane (the plane containing the two instantiations of $\mathbf w$) are two parallel lines.
But $UA$ lies on one of these two lines and $CB$ lies on the other.
Therefore $UA \parallel CB$.
